# Parse Cloud Query array contains value

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a parse data model like...

```
Parent
------
children - Array of pointers to Child objects
```

I'm trying to create a query that says...

> Find all Parents where the children array contains the specific Child object.

It's sort of the opposite of this function from the docs.

```
query.containedIn("playerName", ["Jonathan Walsh", "Dario Wunsch", "Shawn Simon"]);
// note you can also do this with object pointers which is EXACTLY opposite to what I want.
```

This will find all the `players` where the `playerName` is contained in the given array.

I want this but I want to give a value and that value to be in the array for the key.

I imagine it's something like...

```
query.contains("children", someChildObject);
```

but the docs for `contains` shows it only works for substrings of strings.

How would I do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `query.equalTo` for key with an array type.

Try query like following:

```
var ChildClass = Parse.Object.extend('ChildClass');
var childObj = new ChildClass();
childObj.id = 'objId';
// you don't need to do above if you already have the object.

query.equalTo("children", childObj);
...
```

ref. [Queries on Array Values](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-arrays)

Comment: Ah, I didn't think equalTo would work but it seems you're right :) Thanks